# Stack the lables of an axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a bar graph and showing multiple values on the x axis. By default they are shown in series with a "," separating them as shown below. Instead of a coma how could I show the values stacked on top of each other as drawn on the image below? This would save space on the x-axis to allow for bigger graphs when I want to show multiple values.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

dfex = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['LA', 'SF', 'Dallas'],
 'Lakes': [3, 9, 6],
 'Rivers': [1, 0, 0],
 'State': ['CA', 'CA', 'TX'],
 'Waterfalls': [2, 4, 5]})

myplot = dfex.plot(x=['City','State'],kind='bar',stacked='True')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply hack the x-axis tick labels to achieve what you want.

```
ticks = myplot.xaxis.get_ticklabels()
new_ticks = ['\n'.join(t.get_text()[1:-1].split(', ')) for t in ticks]
myplot.xaxis.set_ticklabels(new_ticks)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vlas! I'm trying to figure out how to do this with sns.factorplot as well. It's returning this error for ticks = fplot.xaxis.get_ticklabels() -> AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'xaxis'. Do you know how to get the tick labels for factorplots?

Comment: Afaik `FacetGrid` is basically a collection of subplots, so if you want to access the individual `xaxis` instances you'll have to do it through something like `fplot.fig.axes[0].xaxis`.